# Android Data Insert and URI

Tags: android, database, service, uri

So I am at a loss on how to solve this due to my full knowledge of the Android SDK.  I've created a service that receives data off of the a network (call it MyService).  Other applications then register a URI with this service with an ID for a message type.  When a message of the correct message type comes in I need MyService to insert the data into the application database with the registered URI.

The "Other" applications are unknown to MyService.  So given what I have... how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify some sort of mapping between a given URI and what database you want to put the received data in. How you specify this mapping is where it seems like you're having issue. When other applications register a URI with your service, why not have them also specify a database in which any received messages for that URI should be put.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question.  I have a service that is running.  Third party applications then register URI's with the service through AIDL (Application bind to the service to do this).  My service then receives data from the network and identifies what URI the data belongs to... All this works... I'm stuck on how to put the data into the database given just its URI.

Comment: The problem falls with knowing the layout of the registered database.

Comment: Why not pass along the information about the database layout as well? Or better yet, just encapsulate the database in a content provider and include a URI specifying where they received message should go in the content provider.

Comment: Yea I thought about passing the layout just didn't want to worry about getting it through AIDL.  But this solution would work.  I've decided to just pass off the raw data for the client application to handle, which would essentially be like specifying the DB layout in the Content Provider.  Thanks for your help.